# Javascript upgrade when upgrading from MOSS 2007 to SP 2010?

Tags: migration, upgrade

When migrating from MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2010 how do I upgrade client side scripts (javascript, jquery, etc) running on the MOSS 2007 sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which scripts are you referring to? Out of the box, SharePoint doesn't use jQuery, so anything you've added to the environment would need to be manually upgraded by you during the upgrade process. Customizations that affect the DOM will likely break during the upgrade process since the DOM structure of the 2010 look and feel is so different from the 2007 versions.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification webdes03. The scripts that I am referring to are the ones that are added to Content Editor Web Part (by either a developer or user). Also, I would like to know if there is any way by which I would come to know about all the scripts running in my SharePoint environment, so as to upgrade them all. Thanks in advance...

Comment: You could potentially use search to search for any .js filetypes, but there's no guarantee that'd find everything. There is no way to locate all of those scripts; one of the drawbacks to the CEWP approach.